How Can I Wrap Multiple Outline Buttons On A Container or Card
I am trying to Wrap several outline buttons on a Container or Card. I want the buttons to wrap round the container or card widgets.
The challenge is that we don't know exactly how many of these outline buttons will fill a line hence we need the container to wrap the buttons.
The UI should look like this.


Although the answer can be provided for resolving the issue, I'd recommend adding the code that you have tried so far...

This kind of layout is called Chips, I would suggest to maybe look at this article. And in general, adding Widgets line by line as much as fits is done with a Wrap widget

Refere ChoiceChip hope its help to you.

Basically, the Wrap widget is what you are looking for!
Example:
Container(
          color: Colors.grey,
          child: Wrap(
            spacing: 5.0,
            runSpacing: 5.0,
            children: [
              button("Button One"),
              button("Button Two"),
              button("Button Three"),
              button("Button Four"),
              button("Button Five"),
              button("Button Six"),
              button("T"),
              button("Long text goes here"),
              button("Another long text goes here as well"),
              button("Hello, world"),
              button("Button"),
            ],
          ),
        ),

button widget:
  // Example child widget
  Widget button(String text) {
    return OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      style: ButtonStyle(
        foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),
        shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
          RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Text(text),
    );
  }

The example contains a hard-coded OutlinedButtons, feel free to add the proper widgets (such as ChoiceChip or standard Chip).
The Wrap dynamically takes care of moving (wrapping) its children to the next line. Note that the outer Container height is dynamic based on its child (Wrap) height.
Output:


I am getting thie error: The method 'button' isn't defined for the type 'Topics'.

@CliffOdebalaClarke Of course :) button is just a method that I implemented to show the output, it's just an example, and you could add your widgets there. I added it as well anway.

You can use the widget below.
The Wrap widget ensures that the buttons automatically move to the next line when they don’t fit horizontally.
 class TrendingSearches extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> trendingSearches = [
    'caitlin clark',
    'nfl schedule 2024',
    'caitlin clark',
    'nfl schedule 2024', 'caitlin clark',
    'nfl schedule 2024', 'caitlin clark',
    'nfl schedule 2024', 'caitlin clark',
    'nfl schedule 2024', 'caitlin clark',
    'nfl schedule 2024', 'caitlin clark',
    'nfl schedule 2024', 'caitlin clark',
    'nfl schedule 2024'];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Trending Searches'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey),
        child: Wrap(
          spacing: 8.0, // Placement between elements
          runSpacing: 8.0, // Bottom line transition spaces
          children: trendingSearches.map((searchTerm) {
            return InputChip(
              onDeleted: () {},
              onPressed: () {},
              onSelected: (bool value) {},
              label: Text(searchTerm),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


How do I add an onPress or OnTap method to these buttons?

I updated the code. I added InputChip. You can use onSelected, onDeleted, onPressed methods. @CliffOdebalaClarke

Try below code hope its help to you. Refer Wrap class
Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5, horizontal: 5),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey, borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            Text('Trending searches'),
            const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
            Wrap(
              spacing: 5.0,
              children: List<Widget>.generate(
                trendingSearchesList.length,
                (int index) {
                  return Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      vertical: 5,
                    ),
                    child: OutlinedButton(
                      style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                          foregroundColor: Colors.white),
                      onPressed: () {
                        print('Button Click No -$index');
                        print(
                            'Tapped Item - ${trendingSearchesList[index].toString()}');
                      },
                      child: Text(trendingSearchesList[index].toString()),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ).toList(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),

Result-> 
